# How do I desalinate seawater?

Tags: survival, water-purification, sea

I know I shouldn't drink seawater (because of the salt it contains), but how can I desalinate it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to distill it - I'm assuming that freezing is not an option (unless you're camping in the extreme latitudes). This is easiest, as the ice on top is almost pure water.

Where you don't have a freezer available - boiling the water, capturing the steam and condensing it back to water will provide pure water.

Comment: This method can be achieved using a plastic tarp or other impermeable membrane (raincoat). Boil water below, with the tented tarp above funneled into a container.

Comment: If no heat source is available and you have a clear plastic tarp, use the solar energy of the sun to evaporate the salt water and capture the condensation. Make sure to angle the tarp and create a wrinkle for the liquid to drain into a container.

Comment: Distillation doesn't work 100%, the steam also contains some salt... when I was young I grown crystals and once I got for 1 week away. There was a book near the saturated salt solution where the crystals have grown. When I returned from vacation, it was completely covered with salty coating with crystals. So it doesn't work 100%.

Comment: it might not be 100% but it is better than nothing

Answer (score 11):

Outdoors you can dig a hole and build [SOLAR STILL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_still). It is quick and dirty but works very well and it is time tested.

[image]

Or you can put big plastic bag over brach with a lot of leaves on it and put rock on the bottom to capture the water. Make sure you don't do it on foliage that is toxic to people.

[image]

If you have the bucks you could get a portable [Reverse osmosis filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_osmosis).

[Electrolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water) turns the salt water into oxygen and hydrogen then recombine them and the result is pure water.

Comment: +1 for the solar still: but how do you 'recombine' hydrogen and oxygen? other than combusting the hydrogen?

Comment: @HorusKol: You burn them, and make a sizable explosion. Hydrogen is _dangerous_, and the danger arises from particular concentrations, which make it detonate, instead of burning. Also careful with the electrolyzed water. That most likely contains a mixture of bleach and lye.

Comment: My recommendation for solar stills is to look for an appropriate dip rather than dig a hole since you'll sweat buckets digging, which rather defeats the object.

The latter does not help with sea water.